# How to Map String value on x-axis with String value on y-axis in android graphview

Tags: android, android-graphview

I can take Subjects on `X-axis` and grades[`A1`,`A2`,`B1`,`B2`,`C1`,`C2`,`D1`,`D2`,`E1`,`E2`] on y-axis 
and I am mapping like(`English`,`A1`).

Please help me with the above graph?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set numbers for each mark and subject like

`A1 = 1;
A2 = 2;
B1 = 3`
...

`English = 1;
Math = 2`
...

Because DataPoint needs a double as input. 
After this you edit the labels and input a switch statement or sth. Like that to replace the numbers with marks/subj.